# Heading with link not listed in VoiceOver Headings rotor

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

To make a site I'm working on WCAG compliant I'm adding semantic structuring to it.

I've noticed if the heading is additionally a link it is not picked up by the screed reader I'm using (VoiceOver).

That is:

```
<h1>This is a H1 heading</h1>
<h3><a href="someurl.html">This is a H3 heading</a></h3>
<h4>This is a H4 heading</h4>
```

Shows up in the rotor (`ctrl-opt-u`) as:

```
1: This is a H1 heading
4: This is a H4 heading
```

If you move the `h3` text out of `<a>` tags so `This is a H3 heading` is a text node, or switch to using `span`, the header DOES show up in the rotor.

My question is this:  Is there a way to get the `h3` to show up on the Headings rotor while keeping it as a hyperlink?

If anyone knows if this is a similar problem for NVDA or JAWS that information would be appreciated too.

Comment: I should note using the `ctrl-opt-cmnd-h` voice over command to advance to the next heading DOES visit the `h3`.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Voiceover, perhaps email this to accessibility@apple.com

Comment: To me this is a bug too, shot Apple Accessibility an email.  I'll let you guys know if they respond.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try putting the whole heading inside the anchor?

A bit of an odd work around, I know.

I suspect `VO` shouldn't work like that. For what it's worth, I just tried that code with `NVDA` and it works, both in the virtual cursor type mode (arrowing up and down) and using `H` to jump to the next heading. So it seems fine to me.

Comment: Putting the heading inside the link `<a …><h3>hello</h3></a>` doesn't read the heading. VO says "visited, link, hello". I'd prefer it to say "heading level 3, visited, link, hello"